# What are the ways and how to consume a web service in Apache cordova using Visual studio 2015

Tags: web-services, rest, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova, taco

I want to consume web service whether SOAP or REST api in my Visual studio 2015 apache cordova application. The list widgets which I have on my UI, I want to bind the values retrieved from these web services.
How to do so?

Presently I have a API url which provides jaosn data. It would be really helpful to know how its done with it.

Also, if available, provide the link where I can study to do so.

Answer (score 2):

For web based Application(Cordova), we usually use [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for data Transfer.

Sample Codes:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "your api url here", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

> Also, if available, provide the link where I can study to do so.

You can refer to the following links:

[Getting Started-AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

[Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)